# How to detect different xml format with php?

Tags: php, xml

**Problem**

I have 2 XML files in a different format. Hence, when a user send the XML file, my PHP is required to read and identify how to sort the XML file. Is there any way for me to identify the XML format when I read using PHP so that I can extract the appropriate information from it? Thanks.

**FORMAT 1**

```
<xml>
    <from></from>
</xml>
```

**FORMAT 2**

```
   <xml>
       <to></to>
   </xml>
```

Comment: They don't have same name true? So you can take data without problem with different name no?

Comment: And how they are different? What `<xml>` here - root node or your attempt to write `<?xml ....?>`?

Comment: If you are using SimpleXML, you can check if a node is set by `isset($data->to)` - where `$data` is the SimpleXML loaded.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are distinct elements which you can detect as part of the XML, then you can check if they are present.  Using SimpleXML...

```
$xml = '<xml>
    <to></to>
</xml>';

$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);

if ( isset($data->from) ){
    echo "From format";
}
else if ( isset($data->to) ){
    echo "To format";
}
else    {
    echo "Uknown format";
}
```

Comment: Hi Nigel thanks for the solution. Let's say if the xml is like a html file with lots of tag. Would you still recommend simplexml ?

Comment: If you are just reading the data, you could stick with SimpleXML. DOMDocument is better at constructing and manipulating data, but (IMHO) more verbose and not so adept at reading XML hierarchies.